# How does ML.NET detect the end of a method-chain in C#?

Tags: c#

I ran into a bug using ML.NET Transforms.

The pipeline is set up by declaring a Transform and then appending more transforms to it, like so:

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "image",
                    imageWidth: imageWidth, 
                    imageHeight: imageHeight, 
                    inputColumnName: nameof(ImageNetData.Image)) // Resizes the image
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "image",
                    inputColumnName: "image")) //Transforms the image to floats
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(modelFile: modelLocation,
                    outputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelOutput}, 
                    inputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelInput }));// Runs the image through the network
//Output: An EstimatorChain that runs ALL THREE above steps
```

But running the same code without method-chaining produces a different output.

```
var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.ResizeImages(outputColumnName: "image",
                    imageWidth: imageWidth, 
                    imageHeight: imageHeight, 
                    inputColumnName: nameof(ImageNetData.Image)); // Resizes the image
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.ExtractPixels(outputColumnName: "image",
                   inputColumnName: "image")); //Transforms the image to floats
pipeline.Append(mlContext.Transforms.ApplyOnnxModel(modelFile: modelLocation,
                    outputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelOutput}, 
                    inputColumnNames: new[] { TinyYoloModelSettings.ModelInput }));// Runs the image through the network
//Output: An EstimatorChain that runs only the first step
```

What is it about method chaining that produces a different output?

Comment: What does the implementation of Append look like at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume pipeline is immutable and Append returns copy of pipeline with transform appended, so original pipeline is not affected.

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.data.transformerchain-1?view=ml-dotnet#extension-methods)

> "Create a new transformer chain, by appending another transformer to the end of this transformer chain."

Comment: That's clever. If there isn't a direct answer to the title question, I'll accept this and reword the original question to fit the answer

Comment: It's clever, but also a clear violation of expectations... thanks Microsoft

Comment: What you mean about "end of a method chain detected"?

Comment: The wording in the docs suggests that the pipeline creator checks the "last method" in the method chain for a certain type of method. But I think the same effect can be done with your solution

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.learningpipelineextensions.append?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_LearningPipelineExtensions_Append__1_Microsoft_ML_IEstimator_Microsoft_ML_ITransformer__Microsoft_ML_IEstimator___0__Microsoft_ML_Data_TransformerScope_ "Create a new transformer chain, by appending another transformer to the end of this transformer chain." So it creates new